# Mocking Enum using unittest.mock does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm trying to Mock an enum in Python so that I can assert whether a method of the class tested calls a method on the enum.

This does not work as expected. The method in question is never called because an identity comparison of the mock with the actual enum always fails.

```
class ProcessorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_do_something(self):
        # Mock library does not work with enums..
        self.mock_camera = mock.create_autospec(Camera.exit)

        self.processor.process(self.mock_camera)

        # => always leads to "failed"
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_camera.do_something.called,
                        "Failed")

class Camera(Enum):
    entrance = 1
    exit = 2

    def do_something(self):
        return True

class Processor:
    def process(self, camera):
        # this comparison always resolves to false
        if camera is Camera.exit:
            # never reached
            camera.do_something()
```

Comment: Have you tried patching that method, rather than replacing the whole enumerator member? There's no way to mock identity.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, that worked. Kind of new with testing in Python but indeed you can't mock identity. This worked: `Camera.exit.do_something = mock.MagicMock()` and `self.assertTrue(Camera.exit.do_something.called, "failed")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to create a mock member of an enumeration, just [patch that method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object):

```
from enum import Enum
import unittest


class Camera(Enum):
    entrance = 1
    exit = 2

    def do_something(self):
        return True


class Processor:

    def process(self, camera):
        if camera is Camera.exit:
            camera.do_something()


class TestProcessor(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_processor_process(self):
        with unittest.mock.patch.object(Camera, 'do_something') as mock_method:
            Processor().process(Camera.exit)
            mock_method.assert_called_once_with()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now you can pass a real member, but intercept calls to `do_something`. This gets around the fact that there's no way to mock identity.

Comment: Just solved it on my own based on your comment but I'll gladly accept your answer

Comment: @edwardmp you're welcome to post your own answer if you did it differently. Note that it's better to correspond with your own example - what is `open_barrier`?